# Swift, error: ambiguous use of subscript

Tags: json, swift, subscript

I am getting this error: ambiguous use of subscript, and I don't know how to resolve it. Could you please help ?
The first one is at the line:

> next = next[sub]

Here is the code:

```
public subscript(path: [SubscriptType]) -> JSON {
    get {
        if path.count == 0 {
            return JSON.nullJSON
        }

        var next = self
        for sub in path {
            next = next[sub]
        }
        return next
    }
    set {

        switch path.count {
        case 0: return
        case 1: self[path[0]] = newValue
        default:
            var last = newValue
            var newPath = path
            newPath.removeLast()
            for sub in Array(path.reverse()) {
                var previousLast = self[newPath]
                previousLast[sub] = last
                last = previousLast
                if newPath.count <= 1 {
                    break
                }
                newPath.removeLast()
            }
            self[newPath[0]] = last
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much,

Comment: Is it key subscription or index subscription? That's what *ambiguous* means.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to tell the compiler what data type `self` is, like:

`var next = self as? [String]`

or

`var next = self as? [String:AnyObject]`

If you're not sure you will want to do a branching condition like

```
if let next = self as? [String] 
     { // foo } 
else if let next = self as? [String:AnyObject] 
     { // bar }
```

(I am not sure exactly what type `self` is here, you may need other types than `[String]` and `[String:AnyObject]`).